# asp.net - Warning in a plain and simple HTML5 select element

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2012

I'm going around for quite some hours now how to resolve this warning. Although I know that the code will run just fine but I can't stand to see this warning.
I have this

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
</select>
```

and Visual Studio is giving me this Warning

> Warning   1   Validation (XHTML5): This attribute name must be followed by
>   an equal (=) sign and a value. If the value is in quotation marks, the
>   quotation marks must match.

although [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) states and I'm sure that the correct code is my code above. And I've read somewhere that in Visual Studio 2013 they resolved this issue (I'm using 2012) But in the comment section they said that they're using 2015 but still the warning pops. Any fix?

Comment: If you don't want to follow the rules of XHTML, then don't validate against XHTML.

Comment: Since you mention HTML5 and W3schools, I thought it might be useful to also check out the W3C official spec for HTML 5 regarding attributes: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/syntax.html#syntax-attributes - which specifically states that empty-valued attributes may be written as just the attribute name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the multiple attribute must be defined as

```
<select multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: So I must follow the XHTML standard? Sorry for the question but I'm not familliar with XHTML. Because I know in HTML5 there is some kind of `checked` `disabled` only. So in XHTML I can still use that by `checked=checked`?

Comment: @Fiendcoder1 yes in XHTML you must be explicitly verbose, like `disabled="disabled"`. In visual studio the editor will validate your html based on your settings in the html schema validator. According to the error you show above, it looks like VS is validating according to XHTML5. Information on VS html schema and how to change it is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f940516c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why is html5 validated against xhtml rules?